# Downvote + on hold for my questions

Tags: discussion

I have posted https://serverfault.com/questions/823389/how-to-route-traffic-between-my-nics-on-linux-which-connected-to-proxy-server?noredirect=1#comment1049296_823389 and got marked as "on hold" because it is believed that it is off topic.

I believe this is a legitimate question as I believe there must be a way to do forwarding through some sort of ssh port forwarding or playing with the routing rules etc. I do not believe this is something IT should care because all the traffic will come from my account through the web proxy anyways.

Can we please discuss if my question is really off topic or not?

Answer (score 10):

The problem here is that you "do not believe this is something IT should care" about, but the fact is, IT *cares very much* about unauthorized devices on the network.

We have never accepted questions about circumventing IT security controls, and since most of us *are* in the IT departments at our various jobs, it's likely that we never will. What you're doing is a great way to lose your job. You really should be talking to your IT department about your actual needs, so that they can provide something appropriate.

Furthermore, we do not accept every question about computers and networking. That is not what this site is about. Even if you weren't trying to get yourself fired from your job, this is not something that IT would reasonably be doing. This site is about professional IT operations.

Comment: And as for migrating this question to [SO]:It's even *more* off-topic there - they deal with programming and software development.

Comment: How is this any different than someone installing a virtual machine and doing a NAT on the host machine's connection. So this is also an unauthorised machine but IT will not be able to control it or? In that sense, I thought the web proxy is what IT cares. All the activity on my username on the web proxy is my responsibility. The purpose of my question is not getting around IT rules. More of a "I have a scrutinised way of accessing web, how can I share it?".

Comment: It might not be different from that either, but that's also something that IT has to approve and make it work for you.

Comment: And the proper answer to the question ("I have... how can I share it") is "talk to your IT department". You do not circumvent them. You do not figure out ways to make it look as though you have only one device while you do in fact have several. And you most definitely do not go to the place where IT department staff congregate to help one another out and try to find help to circumvent them.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not topical because it is not about administering systems in a business environment - that is what your IT department does. Your question would likely be on topic for U&L or SU. However I would not migrate it because quite frankly it's crappy and we try hard not to migrate crap.

Why is it crappy?

- It doesn't provide sufficient information about the environment, we're lead to believe there is a proxy server and a hub. What??? Who uses hubs these days? What kind of access do you want? What kind of proxy server is it ?
- This is your playground too - that sounds very professional don't you mean lab ?
- You suggest that  *... somehow need to set up some sort of forwarding...* Well, did you try researching that ? Did you try anything ? Or did you just type some crap into a box on Stackexchange ?